# Flutter BottomNavigationBar change page index or call function again after dispose (with arguments?)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` with 4 pages in my `main.dart`.

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {
      'page': Screen1(),
    },
    {
      'page': Screen2(),
    },
    {
      'page': Screen3(),
    },
    {
      'page': Screen4(),
    },
  ];
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
```

When user selects `_selectedPageIndex` 2, I'm hiding the `BottomNavigationBar` and show the Page in fullscreen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: _selectedPageIndex != 2
          ? Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              GlobalPlayerSmall(),
              BottomNavigationBar(
                onTap: _selectPage,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                unselectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(130, 130, 130, 1),
                selectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(236, 37, 105, 1),
                selectedFontSize: 10,
                iconSize: 22,
                currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: Text(
...
```

Now when we are on `Screen3()`, where we hided the `BottomNavigationBar` and we have to navigate back, im using `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');` to come back to the default screen. (I cant change the `_selectedPageIndex` as the `BottomNavigationBar` is hidden and we don't have access to the value)

Now my problem: In my `main.dart` I'm using initState for a function. If we `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');` the function gets disposed.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupValues();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    exampleFunction.stop();
  }
```

How can I call `setupValues();` again, after `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');` OR is there any other idea to get this work?

Appreciate every idea you have!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

File where `BottomNavigationBar`, `_pages` map and `_selectedPageIndex` are:

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/';


  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
...
```

File where I have to access `_selectedPageIndex` -- `Screen3()`:

```
class Screen3 extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/find';

  @override
  _Screen3State createState() => _Screen3State();
}

class _Screen3State extends State<Screen3> {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it static and use the class to access it i.e: `MyWidget._selectedPageIndex()`

Comment: thank you very much! I tried to implement it with no success, im not sure if im doing it right, can you provide me an example to my case?. Can you show me how to access it? I edited my code, so you can see the hirarchy.

Comment: I provided some more code, I never accessed values before from classes, maybe Im missing something because of the widgets states or something else.